# Using RxJS Subject instead of Observable in Angular Tour of Heroes

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

Can someone explain why at the end of the [Tour of Heroes tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial/tour-of-heroes/toh-pt6#search-by-name) for Angular, when implementing the `search` function, we created a `searchTerm` property from the RxJS Subject class and not the usual Observable class and why it's private property?

```
export class HeroSearchComponent implements OnInit {
  heroes$!: Observable<Hero[]>;
  private searchTerms = new Subject<string>();

  constructor(private heroService: HeroService) {}

  // Push a search term into the observable stream.
  search(term: string): void {
    this.searchTerms.next(term);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.heroes$ = this.searchTerms.pipe(
      // wait 300ms after each keystroke before considering the term
      debounceTime(300),

      // ignore new term if same as previous term
      distinctUntilChanged(),

      // switch to new search observable each time the term changes
      switchMap((term: string) => this.heroService.searchHeroes(term)),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The tutorial [_says why_](https://angular.io/tutorial/tour-of-heroes/toh-pt6#the-searchterms-rxjs-subject) - it's an observable that's also a _source_ of data. You can't send a `next` value into an Observable, they're effectively read-only.

Comment: This question may also help understand it a bit better: [What is the difference between Observable and a Subject in rxjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47537934/what-is-the-difference-between-observable-and-a-subject-in-rxjs)

Comment: As to why it's split into public and private like that, think encapsulation and control. Only the owner gets to push new values into the read-write Subject, everyone _outside_ sees only the read-only Observable. That probably makes more sense with a service than a component example, e.g. see [my blog](http://blog.jonrshar.pe/2017/Apr/09/async-angular-data.html) (_"the subscribers can't push new data into it, so we know any new state must come from within the service itself"_).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is it recommended to make subjects in your service private, and just expose them via a .asObervable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73648114/why-is-it-recommended-to-make-subjects-in-your-service-private-and-just-expose)

Comment: Thank you i get it now.
Tutorial's explanation was not very clear.